# Why does firefox still display website ssl to be 128 bit encrypted after changing to 256

Tags: ssl, firefox

I recently renewed an ssl certificate to use SHA-2 but on firefox the website still shows to be SHA-1 and 128 bit encrypted, on all other browsers it show SHA-2 , 256 bit.
Can anybody help me with this problem please.

Suraj

Comment: Try this: Tools > Clear Private Data and only put a checkmark before Authenticated Sessions -> Clear Now

Comment: A certificate has a hash, but it’s distinct from the HMAC used in symmetric encryption. The most prominently-displayed one will be the latter, and renewing your certificate will change the former. Check your ciphersuite (and Firefox version).

Answer (score 0):

That's because "SHA-256" talks about the size of the output of a hash function, while "128-bit encryption" talks about the size of a key used as input to a symmetric encryption algorithm, i.e. not at the same thing at all. There is no relation whatsoever between these two figures.

Comment: However, that doesn't explain why "on firefox the website still shows to be SHA-1".